# DOMDocument - Load xml rss - failed to open stream

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I want to get links from a rss url . This is my code :

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load("http://www.alef.ir/rssdx.gmyefy,ggeltshmci.62ay2x.y.xml");
$arrFeeds = array();
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {

    $title = $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $title=strip_tags($title);
    $link=$node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
```

I've used this code for several others URLs and all of them worked but on this one I get:

> **Warning:**
>   DOMDocument::load(http://www.alef.ir/rssdx.gmyefy,ggeltshmci.62ay2x.y.xml): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
>   HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in /home/xxxxxxx/domains/xxxxxxx/public_html/data.php on line 14
>   **Warning:**
>   DOMDocument::load(): I/O warning: failed to load external entity "http://www.alef.ir/rssdx.gmyefy,ggeltshmci.62ay2x.y.xml"
>   in /home/xxxxxxx/domains/xxxxxxx/public_html/data.php on line 14
>   http://www.alef.ir/rssdx.gmyefy,ggeltshmci.62ay2x.y.xml

Line 14 is:

```
$doc->load("http://www.alef.ir/rssdx.gmyefy,ggeltshmci.62ay2x.y.xml");
```

Could you help me? Why does this request give me an error?

Thanks

Comment: The URL has a comma in it - perhaps that is throwing the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the code above failed for me and it was not due to the comma as I commented. I found that, using curl, I was able to retrieve the xml file.

```
$c=curl_init('http://www.alef.ir/rssdx.gmyefy,ggeltshmci.62ay2x.y.xml');
curl_setopt( $c, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'nginx-curl-blahblahblah' );
curl_setopt( $c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
$r=curl_exec( $c );
curl_close( $c );

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadxml($r);
$arrFeeds = array();

foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {

    $title=$node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $title=strip_tags($title);
    $link=$node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this code before calling your feed, this will change user agent.

```
$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'user_agent' => 'PHP libxml agent',
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
libxml_set_streams_context($context);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for adding this answer. I was losing my mind trying to figure out the issue with a little bit of third party code, and this was exactly it!